# How to completely delete all files pertaining to a program

Tags: synaptic, lan, permanent-delete

How to delete all files pertaining to a recently installed program that has not worked? I think no one wants to fill their computer with odd bits and ends from aborted installations, dependencies that don‘t pan out &c.

I suppose that I could use a package manager for that, such as Synaptic. But how?

My immediate concern here is how to get rid of all files related to LanMessenger, which I’ve been trying to make work with no success, but seems to keep asking for more and more dependencies. The last time this sort of thing happened, I ended up freezing everything, and it took me days to be able to boot again.

Comment: I thought of that, but the thing is I don’t even know what name LanMessenger travels under. I‘ve already tried ‘lan-messenger’ and ‘lan-msg’, to no avail. Is there an “undo-the-last-[3]-steps” command?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-cache search lan-messenger` to look for packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove all the files belonging to a given package by using

`sudo apt purge <package name>`

So in your case:

`sudo apt purge LanMessenger`

If you also want to remove dependencies which are no longer used, you can then run:

`sudo apt autoremove`